# "Method << does not exist on T.class_of(A)" use of def_delegators with sorbet

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I've got a code that uses Singleton and Forwardable to delegate some methods to the internal `Hash`.

```
class A
  include Singleton

  extend T::Sig

  sig { returns(T::Hash[T.untyped, T.untyped]) }
  attr_reader :stars

  class << self
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators :instance, :<<, :[], :stars
    def_delegators :stars, :length
  end

  sig { void }
  def initialize
    @stars = {}
  end

  sig { params(identifier: String).returns(B) }
  def [](identifier)
    @stars[identifier]
  end
end
```

I use `A << B.new` outside `A` class and when I run `be srb tc` I get `Method << does not exist on T.class_of(A)`. Any suggestions or ideas how I can get rid of this warning?

Comment: It was my bad actually I forgot to run `srb rbi update` when I required forwardable and actually after adding a gem dependency I found out I have to run update command again and it helped

Comment: Thank you @Gregg. That was a good leading point for me to look into a similar error. Just for one's info in general: Turns out these days, `Tapioca` and `tapioca dsl` specifically(more here: https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/blob/b70c59e1037d36262a99bfc0c7b32d5cd9a34692/README.md#generating-rbi-files-for-rails-and-other-dsls) is a recommended way to go especially generate RBI files for dynamic methods,  as I got: 'The srb rbi command is in maintenance mode, please use Tapioca instead.' when I ran: `srb rbi update`